# Javascript: A function that has an input parameter

Tags: javascript, function, input, parameters, output

Brand new programmer in the earliest learning stages here. I am currently on assignment overseas and taking a Javascript class via online college. I recently had an assignment that is racking my brain. I don't have a teacher I can ask so I would like to call upon you all for help. I would ask that please don't just give me the answer, I would enjoy being steered in the right direction but not just handed the answer. So here is the assignment I was given.......

1. Create two files, one named third.html and the other named third.js
2. Write code to create a web page that uses a JavaScript program to output a NASA style count down:
   Ten
   Nine
   ...
   One
   Ignition Start
   Liftoff
   We have Liftoff!
3. Each line must be displayed on the web page.
4. An alert must be used to control when the next line displays.
5. Define a function that has an input parameter which contains the line to output, and displays that line on the web page.
6. Use that function to output each line of the countdown.
7. Each line of the countdown, after the first line, will display after the user clicks "ok" in response to the alert.
8. Use a loop when displaying the numeric part of the countdown.  Numbers can be displayed as numeric digits or words. (Example: 10 or Ten)
9. Use comments and lay the code out so it can be easily followed.

**Here is the javascript I have come up with**

```
for (var count=10; count >= 1; count--) {
    window.alert("Click Okay!");
    document.write(count+"<br />")
}

{
    window.alert("Click Okay!")
    document.write("Ignition Start<br />")
    window.alert("Click Okay!")
    document.write("Liftoff<br />")
    window.alert("Click Okay!")
    document.write("We Have Liftoff!<br />")
}
```

I am not sure if I am just retarded or if it is worded in a weird way. I cannot for the life of me figure out how to do step 5 and step 6 of my assignment. Everything outputs with an alert box that you have to click before the next number is displayed, but I cannot figure out how to define the function that has an input parameter that contains the line to output. Any help in the right direction would be GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: You should make objective questions, not copy and past your home work.

Comment: I don't see you doing #9 correctly :)

Comment: @jaapaurelio If you read my entire question it is very objective. I also stated that I do not want someone to just paste the correct code for me but to explain where I should be looking to find the answer. I guess to explain to me in layman's terms what step 5 and 6 is looking for. This is literally my first week writing JS. I am not here for someone else to do my homework. I merely posted my assignment instructions so if someone were to help me they would see the steps I need to take and where I am getting hung up. I do appreciate your concern.

Comment: @jaapaurelio: To my understanding, the OP's question is "Please point me in the right direction regarding information on how to do steps 5 and six". Read between the lines.

Comment: @DavidKhaykin This is not the full code that I had written. I left out the comments because it has personal information in it such as my name, student ID, and email.

Comment: @BlackHawkChief107: It was a joke I'm writing you an answer with some hints.

Comment: @DavidKhaykin Haha okay, I was a bit thrown off by the first comment accusing me of trying to get you all to do my homework :P

Comment: @BlackHawkChief107 Sorry, my bad.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as you asked for hints and not code, have a look at [w3schools' JS function page](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_functions.asp). Call your function from within your loop.

Answer (score 0):

**Your specific question is for help with #5 and #6:**

Here are some hints to get you in the right direction:

> ## 5 Define a function that has an input parameter which contains the line to output, and displays that line on the web page.

***Ok, Let's think of what we need.***

- To define a function, there is a keyword that you use, followed by parenthesis `()`. The keyword rhymes with the word `junction` and is placed before the parenthesis. Then the actual code of the function goes into curly braces `{ ... }` following (on next lines preferably) the parenthesis.
- How do we add parameters? Easy - you give them a name and place them inside the parenthesis. To use them ***inside*** the function, just use the name; when you call the function, you put the ***value*** which will be passed into the function call as that parameter. Multiple parameters are comma delimited.

> ## 6 Use that function to output each line of the countdown.

- We touched on this briefly already. To "use" a function you have to call it by it's name. You already have the code that writes text to the document. Now, instead of that text, you will use the parameter, which you will pass to the function when you call the function.
- Bonus hint. Your `document.write()` calls will be replaced with calls to your new function. Look for the code in your existing example which is ***repetitive*** and it will help you understand what to put into the function.

Here's a quick link with [some examples on W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_functions.asp)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot David! This just made the light bulb turn on. Now it is starting to click and I realize that I was WAY over thinking this.